# What does "access violation " in context of named pipes in windows mean?

Tags: mql, metatrader5

I'm trying to develop a trader bot. The bot itself is written in mql, while it communicates with a c++ code, to receive trading commands(buy and sell) from it and also, send the latest asset price to it. This communication is being done through named pipes(in the context of windows 10). The problem is that when the mql code tries to write something, I get the following error:

[image: error]

What does this error mean and How can I fix it? thanks.

Bu the way, the function that I use for writing is as follows:

```
int CNamedPipe::WriteUnicode(string message)
  {
   int ushortsToWrite, bytesWritten;
   ushort UNICODEarray[];
   ushortsToWrite = StringToShortArray(message, UNICODEarray);
   WriteFile(hPipe,ushortsToWrite,sizeof(int),bytesWritten,0);
   WriteFile(hPipe,UNICODEarray,ushortsToWrite*sizeof(ushort),bytesWritten,0);
   return bytesWritten;
  }
//+-----------
```

P.S.: My original code was so huge that I could not put it here. I write a shorter version of it with the means of sharing it here. It still generates the same error.The code is in mql, btw.

```
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//|                                                        test3.mq5 |
//|                                  Copyright 2021, MetaQuotes Ltd. |
//|                                             https://www.mql5.com |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
#property copyright "Copyright 2021, MetaQuotes Ltd."
#property link      "https://www.mql5.com"
#property version   "1.00"
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//| Script program start function                                    |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+

enum ENUM_PIPE_ACCESS
  {
   PIPE_ACCESS_INBOUND=1,
   PIPE_ACCESS_OUTBOUND=2,
   PIPE_ACCESS_DUPLEX=3,
  };
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//|                                                                  |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
enum ENUM_PIPE_MODE
  {
   PIPE_TYPE_RW_BYTE=0,
   PIPE_TYPE_READ_MESSAGE=2,
   PIPE_TYPE_WRITE_MESSAGE=4,
  };

#define PIPE_WAIT 0
#define PIPE_NOWAIT 1

#define ERROR_PIPE_CONNECTED 535
#define ERROR_BROKEN_PIPE 109

#define INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE -1
#define GENERIC_READ  0x80000000
#define GENERIC_WRITE  0x40000000
#define OPEN_EXISTING  3
#define PIPE_UNLIMITED_INSTANCES 255
#define MQLTICK_SIZE 40
#define PIPE_BUFFER_SIZE 4096
#define STR_SIZE 255

//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//| DLL imports                                                      |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
#import "kernel32.dll"
int CreateNamedPipeW(string pipeName,int openMode,int pipeMode,int maxInstances,int outBufferSize,int inBufferSize,int defaultTimeOut,int security);
int WaitNamedPipeW(string lpNamedPipeName,int nTimeOut);
bool ConnectNamedPipe(int pipeHandle,int overlapped);
bool DisconnectNamedPipe(int pipeHandle);
int CreateFileW(string name,int desiredAccess,int SharedMode,int security,int creation,int flags,int templateFile);
int WriteFile(int fileHandle,short &buffer[],int bytes,int &numOfBytes,int overlapped);
int WriteFile(int fileHandle,char &buffer[],int bytes,int &numOfBytes,int overlapped);
int WriteFile(int fileHandle,MqlTick &outgoing,int bytes,int &numOfBytes,int overlapped);
int WriteFile(int fileHandle,int &var,int bytes,int &numOfBytes,int overlapped);
int ReadFile(int fileHandle,short &buffer[],int bytes,int &numOfBytes,int overlapped);
int ReadFile(int fileHandle,char &buffer[],int bytes,int &numOfBytes,int overlapped);
int ReadFile(int fileHandle,MqlTick &incoming,int bytes,int &numOfBytes,int overlapped);
int ReadFile(int fileHandle,int &incoming,int bytes,int &numOfBytes,int overlapped);
int CloseHandle(int fileHandle);
int GetLastError(void);
int FlushFileBuffers(int pipeHandle);
#import



void OnStart()
  {
//---

   int buffer_size = PIPE_BUFFER_SIZE;
   string pipeName = "\\\\.\\pipe\\junkypipe";
   int hPipe = CreateNamedPipeW(pipeName, PIPE_ACCESS_DUPLEX,PIPE_TYPE_RW_BYTE,PIPE_UNLIMITED_INSTANCES,buffer_size*sizeof(char),
   buffer_size*sizeof(char),
   0,
   NULL
 );
   
   if(hPipe == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
     {
     Print("Failed to create the pipe");
      
     }else
        {
         Print("Pipe Was Created Successfully");
        }
        
    Print("Waiting For Client");
    
    bool resultOfClientBeingConnect = ConnectNamedPipe(hPipe, NULL);
    
    
    if(resultOfClientBeingConnect)
      {
      
      Print("Some Client Has Connected");
      char buffer[];
      string message = "Hi There";
      StringToCharArray(message, buffer);
      int numBytesWritten;
      WriteFile(hPipe, buffer, buffer_size*sizeof(char) + 1, numBytesWritten, 0);
       
      }else
         {
          Print("Failed to Connect");
         }
   
  }
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: it means you are writing to a bad address, ie have a bug in your code, cant give anymore help than that

Comment: 0xE9000000000 is almost too nice to be a real address (ime) so i would agree with pm100

Comment: You can't use std::string as a parameter type, [use const char*](https://andres.jaimes.net/mql/calling-dll-from-mql/#creating-a-dll-with-c-1)

Comment: Turn on compiler warnings.

Comment: @RaymondChen It is already on and shows nothing helpful. just a bunch of "implicit conversion from 'number' to 'string'

Comment: @HansPassant that is completely wrong. Of course `std::string` can be used as a parameter type.

Comment: An std::string object can only be generated by a C++ compiler, interop with the MQL scripting language requires char*.  The linked example demonstrates well how a string needs to be passed.

Comment: @GeorgeWilhelmHegel It should have told you many things, such as `ushort UNICODEarray[];` is not a legal declaration. You are using an uninitialized variable `bytesWritten`. The types passed to WriteFile are incorrect. https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/be1EK1j3W

Comment: Okay, your update explains the error. You are using a custom declaration of WriteFile that is incorrect. The first and last parameters are 64-bit integers, but you declared them as 32-bit integers. Notice that the crash is trying to write to an address where the bottom 32 bits are integers, but the top bits are nonzero.

Comment: @RaymondChen You mean the fileHandle and overlapped, should be long instead of int?

Comment: I think so. I'm not an expert in mql, but it looks like [the 64-bit integer types are called `long` and `ulong`](https://docs.mql4.com/basis/types/integer/integertypes).

Comment: @Raymond I just tried that and it worked !!!!!!! Thank you !! You're a lifesaver !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @RaymondChen, The problem was finally solved. The declaration of `WriteFile` function was wrong. The `fileHandle` and overlapped parameter should have been `long` or `ulong` instead of `int`.

Answer (score 1):

The culprit is almost certainly:

```
ushort UNICODEarray[];
ushortsToWrite = StringToShortArray(message, UNICODEarray);
```

If this compiles, and that's a big 'if', you have a zero size buffer, but presumably `StringToShortArray()` tries to write to it. You didnt show that function, so it's only a guess.

This code should not compile since it's not valid C++, but maybe your compiler allows it (you could argue that a zero-sized array is a valid construct and make it a language extension, for some reason).

Comment: those lines you mentioned are in mql not c++.

Comment: @GeorgeWilhelmHegel mql and C++ are different languages. If this program isn't C++, then why did you tag it C++? (Also, I cannot find any MQL function called WriteFile.)

Comment: @RaymondChen WriteFile() is a part of kernel32.dll. I tagged it c++ since I thought that, as the program that is working on other side is a c++ program, it may have something to do with that. This "access violation" error is a crazy thing. I have read almost every post regarding it in mql5 forum and no one had a clue about the source of the problem or the probable solution.

Comment: But this program isn't C++. When you tag a question as C++, people expect the code to be in C++. (Also, WriteFile does not appear to be an mql function at all. How can you call C++ functions from mql?)

Comment: @RaymondChen I just edited the tags. I told you about the WriteFile(). It is a part of kernel32.dll . I imported it from that library.

Answer (score 0):

`ushort UNICODEarray[];` is not valid C++ code. An array needs a size specified. If you don't know the size at compile-time, then you have to allocate the array dynamically at runtime, either by using `new[]` or `std::vector`.

Also, this:

```
WriteFile(hPipe,ushortsToWrite,sizeof(int),bytesWritten,0);
WriteFile(hPipe,UNICODEarray,ushortsToWrite*sizeof(ushort),bytesWritten,0);
```

needs to be like this instead:

```
WriteFile(hPipe,&ushortsToWrite,sizeof(int),&bytesWritten,NULL);
WriteFile(hPipe,UNICODEarray,ushortsToWrite*sizeof(ushort),&bytesWritten,NULL);
```

Comment: Those lines are in mql not c++.

Answer (score 0):

the error is here

```
 WriteFile(hPipe, buffer, buffer_size*sizeof(char) + 1, numBytesWritten, 0);
```

the 4th parameter is supposed to be a pointer see

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-writefile

in c++ it would be

```
WriteFile(hPipe, buffer, buffer_size*sizeof(char) + 1, &numBytesWritten, 0);
-------------------------------------------------------^
```

not sure if this is the correct mql way